# Set focus to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

In my web page there is a textbox with width and height  equal to 0. This textbox is used to get the scanned bar code value which should not be visible to the user.

Needs:

1. I want to set focus to the textbox, when i click anywhere in the form.
2. I want to make the cursor invisible.

Geetha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for setting focus,

```
$('#idOfTextBox').focus();
```

will do the trick. You can add that to any click handler, such as

```
$('#idOfFormOrParentDiv').click(function() {
    $('#idOfTextBox').focus();
    $(this).css('cursor', 'none');
});
```

As for hiding the cursor, you could apply a cursor: none to the form or parent div as a style or as in the preceding example change it's css via jquery.

The cursor:none is while the cursor is in the bounds of the element - though this behavior in it's entirety seems obscure and unnecessary (not to mention confusing to the user).

#### Example

Here's an example of using absolute positioning to both hide the input field and its cursor. It focuses the field on load, so if you type, then press the **Go** button, you'll see what you typed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#myTextBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
    top: 0px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    $(document).ready(pageInit);

    function pageInit() {
        $('#btnGo').click(go);
        $('#myTextBox').focus();
    }

    function go() {
        alert($('#myTextBox').val());
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body><div>
<input id='myTextBox' type='text' size='1'>
<input id='btnGo' type='button' value='Go'>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dan: I expect he means the big blinking cursor that shows when the focus is in a text box, not the mouse cursor.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I want to hide the blinking cursor inside the textbox.

Comment: Oh, heh - but if the textarea is 0px x 0px, how would you see it anyway? Otherwise you could have the text area well out of the window viewport (margin-left:1000px; ?) and on it's change event update another textarea that isn't in focus (thus, no blinking cursor) or even a div?

Comment: @Dan: Oh that's too smart; recommend updating the answer text. I just tried it out of curiousity, and it worked a great on Chrome 4, IE7, and Firefox 3.6. They let me focus the text box, but I didn't see anything on-screen. Just set `position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: 0px` on the `input`. At a stroke, that effectively hides the text box *and* the cursor. (I was a bit surprised that I didn't have to wrap it in a container and set the container's `overflow: hidden` style, but I didn't; I guess because it's off to the left, not the right.)

Comment: @Dan: Since I'd done it, I took the liberty of posting in my test/demo page.

Comment: Ah, the power of collaboration! Where's that test/demo page? You cool if we put that in the answer?

Comment: My bad, I was editing it when you did and overwrote it - i rolled back the edit :)